# Create and open file exclusively or timeout in Java

Tags: java, file, nio

is there a better way to create and open file exclusively?

Only thing I could think of was the piece of code down below. The point is to create file and open it for write access exclusively. If the file exists, then wait till it's deleted by other process or timeout and throw exception.

```
    final long MAX_WAIT = 5 * 1000; // 5 seconds
    File tmpFile = new File(configuration.getFilePath().getPath() 
                        + "." + Util.TMP_EXTENSION);
    Path path = tmpFile.toPath();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    FileChannel channel = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            channel = FileChannel.open(path, new HashSet(Arrays.asList(
                          StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                          StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)));

            break;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > (start + MAX_WAIT)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Timeout, couldn't create tmp file '" 
                    + tmpFile.getPath() + "'", ex);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (10 + (Math.random() * 50)));
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ie);
            }
        }
    }

    FileLock lock = null;
    Writer writer = null;

    try {
        lock = channel.lock();
        writer = new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(
                     channel, configuration.getEncoding()));

        //DO REAL WORK HERE
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't write data", ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
            if (lock != null && lock.isValid()) {
                lock.release();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed the file system makes a poor replacement for a messaging system, not that you can't use it that way, but it's not going to be pretty.

Comment: what you need is a file system watcher. Search for  WatchService API